# Converting JavaScript code to AngularJS in the case of dynamic Json arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sharing the java script code i have written, but I'm not able to convert this code to Angularjs. I need this in Angular for my project.

I need output as same as this, any way to do this?

```
var components={
  'name':{
    'fname':'test',
    'lname':'test1'
  },
  'password':'',
  'dim':{
    'dim2':{
      'dim3':''
    }
  },
  'ary':{
    'ar10':{
      'ary2':{
        'ary3':''
      }
    },
    'ary11':'hello'
  }
};

 var result=''; var label=[];

 var mylogic=function(obj,source){ /*console.log(obj,source);*/
  // console.log(typeof components[obj] );
   if(typeof source[obj]=='string'){
     return  obj +' <input placeholder="'+obj+'" type="text" value=""> <br>';
   }else{   //console.log( components[obj] );
     var subObj=source[obj]; var tempObj=[];
      for(item in subObj ){
        console.log(item,'--',subObj);

       tempObj.push(obj+' => ' +mylogic(item,subObj)  );
      }
     return tempObj;
   }
}

 for(component in components){
  result+= mylogic(component,components);
   // console.log('Component',components[component]);
}

var res=document.getElementById('result');
res.innerHTML=result;
```

Comment: @vinod-louis - this is the requirement i need but i don't know how to code in angularjs.

Comment: If the correct answer was "read the docs and learn Angular" then the question should be put on hold as "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , you should know that AngularJs is not a language but a is a JavaScript-based framework. So all you need will be : Read the docs (https://angularjs.org/ or https://angular.io/) and init a new angularJs project to put your current code into